Issues Running Uniswap Interface Locally After Cloning
I recently cloned the Uniswap interface from GitHub and followed the steps to set it up locally. After running "yarn install and yarn web start", I'm encountering several errors and the application is not running locally. Here are the details of the errors:
*Compiled with problems:ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native-dotenv/index.js 1:33-46Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\sshan\OneDrive\Desktop\clement\10\web-interface\node_modules\react-native-dotenv'ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native-dotenv/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 1:9-22Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\sshan\OneDrive\Desktop\clement\10\web-interface\node_modules\react-native-dotenv\node_modules\dotenv\lib'ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native-dotenv/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 1:47-60Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\sshan\OneDrive\Desktop\clement\10\web-interface\node_modules\react-native-dotenv\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'- install 'os-browserify'If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:resolve.fallback: { "os": false }ERROR in ./src/i18n.tsx 21:11-65Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './i18n/locales/translations' in 'C:\Users\sshan\OneDrive\Desktop\clement\10\web-interface\apps\web\src'*

Can someone guide me on how to do please?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I tried to run "yarn install" and "yarn web start" as per the instructions provided in the repository. I was expecting the Uniswap interface to start locally without any issues. Instead, I am encountering these errors.
